# Windows Server 2003 multiple gateways possible solutions

Tags: windows-server-2003, routing, gateway

I have the following problem that keeps me sleepless for the last few nights.

I inherited some servers from the guy who retired, and I noticed that one of the interfaces sometimes gets frozen on one of the servers, making people unable to connect to it.

Now, the details:
We have 3 servers- one is the Database server, which hosts only the DB, and its connected to the Access Server, which also has some IIS-based webserver, which again provides .aspx-based controls for the customers, who visit out 3rd server, on which we host the website. I think the following picture will describe it better:
[Network graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbQs9.png)

The problem is that the Access Server is configured with 2 default gateways (sic!), but after all, according to `route print`, it uses the first ISP gateway:

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   bb.bbb.bbb.241   bb.bbb.bbb.243     10
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   aaa.aa.aaa.129   aaa.aa.aaa.130     10
   bb.bbb.bbb.240  255.255.255.248   bb.bbb.bbb.243   bb.bbb.bbb.243     10
   bb.bbb.bbb.243  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
   bb.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   bb.bbb.bbb.243   bb.bbb.bbb.243     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      1
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.0.97     192.168.0.97     10
     192.168.0.97  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.0.97     192.168.0.97     10
   aaa.aa.aaa.128  255.255.255.248   aaa.aa.aaa.130   aaa.aa.aaa.130     10
   aaa.aa.aaa.130  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
   aaa.aa.aaa.255  255.255.255.255   aaa.aa.aaa.130   aaa.aa.aaa.130     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   bb.bbb.bbb.243   bb.bbb.bbb.243     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.0.97     192.168.0.97     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   aaa.aa.aaa.130   aaa.aa.aaa.130     10
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   bb.bbb.bbb.243   bb.bbb.bbb.243      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.0.97     192.168.0.97      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   aaa.aa.aaa.130   aaa.aa.aaa.130      1
Default Gateway:    aaa.aa.aaa.129
```

Now here is the deal - how can I make it work "normally", or at least as close to normal as it can (So I won't have to RDPlogin and restart the .129 adapter everyday)?

At first, I thought of a simple watchdog script, which will ping the freezing NIC from the second source address, but it failed miserably, because in WS2003 the ping command is still retarded and allows only IPv6 with -S parameter. It looks like there is no fix around that, not even a 3rd party solution, and getting ping.exe straight from Windows 7 doesn't work (Really, I tried that too!)

Then I thought about buying a dual-WAN router, plugging it in between server and ISPs' routers, and forward specified ports to one LAN connection - It should work, as long as we assume that current problems are caused by the NIC in that server, but that's pretty easy to sort out, because we have the WWW server on the same connection, and its uptime is almost 100% for the last year (excluding not-company related failures), but even if I set failover on that interface, the clients' application still uses IP to connect, so it will still report unresponsive to the client, but we would have the main problem fixed.

The third option is doing some magic to the Load Balancing options, using some other software, but AFAIK, it never worked good on windows (and freezing adapters are quite common for me)

There is also fourth option, which is nuking everything and getting a new server and/or system, but here the biggest problem would be license - we are hosting SQL Server DB behind it, server backend which communicates with that DB and returns tables for customers on the web AND our employees (about 200+) who use our company program to communicate with the databases. This obviously needs separate CAL licenses, and W2003 was the last one which didn't need that in Web Edition.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The server seem multihomed as the two route are on two distinct interfaces. Can I ask if the server got multiple NIC, why it's not teamed.

Comment: Well, I never saw a Teamed connection working properly on windows - not even my dual LAN (two separate LANs on one mobo) on my PC could work well, it even froze whole computer sometimes, and that was with something as simple as SLA in LAN. There is some NLB Cluster option, but it requires some domain name, and we don't use any domain on this server.

Comment: Windows can't and doesn't use multiple Default Gateways. If your users/customers access the web server then why are you trying to multihome the access server?

Comment: Based on the info i got the the retiring guy, it was "for redundancy and availability". You know, I saw worse things that happened here, and dual-DG server is one of the easier ones...